# Connecting to internet in the main thread in Android

Tags: android, networkonmainthread

I am looking for a way to make a HttpUrlConnection in the main thread of an application. I know that android doesnt let it happen and gives NetworkOnMainThread exception but i am looking for a way to get around it.

*Async task is not allowed

Comment: Why do you think that this is a sensible thing to do? Why do you think that your users will want your UI to freeze and for your app to possibly crash with an ANR?

Comment: I know it will freeze but it is a requirement from my superior.

Comment: Why does your superior think that this is a sensible thing to do? Why does your superior think that your users will want your UI to freeze and for your app to possibly crash with an ANR?

Comment: I know its not a sensible thing to do and i have done the thing with async task before. But my superior just gave task to do it that way. He says its for learning process

Comment: There are lots of things that one can do "for learning process". For example, you could learn how to boost the security of your app, learn how to improve its accessibility, learn how to support various types of hardware, etc. Learning how to create intentionally lousy code is not a particularly sensible choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // You can perform your task here.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is that the user can not interact until the communication ends I would show a non cancellable dialog, probably a progress dialog, while the communication runs in an AsyncTask.